# Using a image to overlay a section of google map api 3 in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hello I am using  google maps api 3 ,this is the way how I am initializing the map:

```
  myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(19.1113635001101, 72.86958755554201);

                var myOptions = 
                    {
                        zoom: 17,
                        center: myLatlng,
                        panControl: false,
                        zoomControl: true,
                        scaleControl: false,
                        scrollwheel: false,
                        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                     }
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

I also have image-map(vector/raster) of entire location which I want to overlay onto the above map(so that overlayed section would be hide google maps(default) underneath ),is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/ProjectedOverlayTest2.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps JS API supports this with: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GroundOverlay?